# what web server is used by default for docker for .NET

Tags: docker, .net-core

I was following example docker for .NET core. There I created the dockerfile as per tutorial. I build the image and successfully run it on port 8081:80. so I can see my application running on localhost:8081. But I have some confusion there, how it is running, which server actually is responsible for running the container. I am a bit confused here cause I don't have the clear picture of what is happening there. Any resource will be much appreciated. Thanks.

here is my dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

Comment: And your dockerfile looks how ?

Comment: it is the basic one. updating the question

Comment: Hi, it appears that Kestrel is the default web server specified by the ASP.NET Core project templates see: **[Web server implementations in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows)**

Answer (score 3):

By looking at the source Dockerfile -

- [sdk Dockerfile](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/b3483ec9136d733f18a78b2f3e916fa3a2321784/src/sdk/3.1/alpine3.12/amd64/Dockerfile) which builds on top of
- [aspnet Dockerfile](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/b3483ec9136d733f18a78b2f3e916fa3a2321784/src/aspnet/3.1/alpine3.12/amd64/Dockerfile) which builds on top of
- [runtime Dockerfile](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/b3483ec9136d733f18a78b2f3e916fa3a2321784/src/runtime/3.1/alpine3.12/amd64/Dockerfile) which builds on top of
- [runtime-dep Dockerfile](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/b3483ec9136d733f18a78b2f3e916fa3a2321784/src/runtime-deps/3.1/alpine3.12/amd64/Dockerfile) (which builds on top of the alpine image of course)

None of them install or configure any other web servers (Nginx, Apache etc.) to override the [default web server of ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows) so it has to be **Kestrel**.

Comment: so, mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 this image has the kestrel server I assume, to run docker .net container. correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Correct, `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1` is created by the Dockerfile above.